# EditText requestFocus() doesn't work on api < 20

Tags: android, android-edittext

I've got a view which contains 4 edit texts for pin passing. What I want them to do with this is that when user puts a digit into the first edit text, focus is changed and goes to the second edit text. From second to third and from third to fourth. Here is the code:

```
private View.OnKeyListener onKeyListener = new View.OnKeyListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onKey(final View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (isKeycodeADigit(keyCode) && event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            switch (v.getId()) {
                case R.id.passcode_first:
                    requestEditTextFocus(mSecondDigit);
                    replaceDigitIfEditTextNotEmpty(mFirstDigit, keyCode);
                    break;
                case R.id.passcode_second:
                    replaceDigitIfEditTextNotEmpty(mSecondDigit, keyCode);
                    requestEditTextFocus(mThirdDigit);
                    break;
                case R.id.passcode_third:
                    replaceDigitIfEditTextNotEmpty(mThirdDigit, keyCode);
                    requestEditTextFocus(mFourthDigit);
                    break;
                case R.id.passcode_fourth:
                    replaceDigitIfEditTextNotEmpty(mFourthDigit, keyCode);
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
};
private void requestEditTextFocus(final EditText editText) {
    editText.requestFocus();
    int selection = editText.length() == 0? 0 : 1;
    editText.setSelection(selection);
}
```

Everything works fine on api >= 20 but on lower androids focus isn't passed forward. 
Any ideas why?